# unable to retrieve a div element using jquery id selector,when Email ID used as the Div ID

Tags: jquery

I am unable to use email id as a Div ID with jquery .

When I use `$("#xyz@gmail.com")` to access div , I am facing the following error

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #xyz@gmail.com

I am not able to retrieve  using jquery selector. I just want to know why email id can't be used as a jquery selector and workaround for the same.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Escape the @, just like it is explained in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Comment: @FelixKling it must be escaped the . too or it'll be treated as class selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape special character `@` and `.` with two backslashes `\\`. From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

```
$("#xyz\\@gmail\\.com")
```

Comment: you also need to escape `.`

Answer (score 1):

If you use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|*}~** ) as a  part of your html element properties name(id,class etc), you must escape the character with two backslashes.

try this:

```
$("#xyz\\@gmail\\.com").html("asdasdasadadeasdasdads");
```

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/97/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Meanwhile if you wants to use this id Use the Backslashes before the special charter.
And use Backslashes before any other symbol which is meaning full in sense of html tags.

Like Class is use as '.' (dot)

so if you cannot use `\\` before '.' jquery takes it as class with parent of `#xyz\\@gmail`

so use it as

```
$("#aa\\@gmail\\.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special character `@` and `.` in the selector using `\\`:

```
$("#xyz\\@gmail\\.com")
```

Quick ref about selectors:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes \\. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/T3j8y/

Comment: you also need to escape `.`

Comment: @AwladLiton I see while I'm building the fiddle, thanks for the comment